# how to compile JShop2 src

Tags: java, github

I'm working with JShop2 [GitHub](https://github.com/mas-group/jshop2). I'm having trouble with the installation; it says:

> After unzipping the JSHOP2 zipped file in any directory, set the
>   CLASSPATH environment variable to include (replacing JSHOP2_DIRECTORY
>   with the directory where JSHOP2 is unzipped):
>
> - in Windows: JSHOP2_DIRECTORY\bin\antlr.jar;JSHOP2_DIRECTORY\bin\JSHOP2.jar;

How can I set these environmental variables? I don't have bin folder as shown in the path --> JSHOP2_DIRECTORY\bin\

I just read that i need to compile `src` to get bin folder, but I don't know how to do that. Please help.

Comment: Have you implement any example.. i am new to Jshop2 and unable to understood syntax of given examples. can you explain.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still add the environmental variables even if the `bin` folder doesn't exist yet. Just make sure you restart your command prompt after you added the new environmental variables, for them to be picked up.

As for building the source in Windows, looking at the [readme](https://github.com/mas-group/jshop2/blob/master/README), their `make.bat` seems to be missing. You can create an issue in github to notify them. Meanwhile, you can use something like [`MinGW`](http://www.mingw.org/) to run `make` on Windows.

After installing `MinGW`, you may have to execute

```
copy c:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe c:\MinGW\bin\make.exe
```

if `make.exe` didn't get created during the installation. Then you should be able to build the project by executing `make` from your jshop2 root folder.

Comment: I just added this as my environmental variable --> D:\Java\jshop2-master\bin\antlr.jar;D:\Java\jshop2-master\bin\JSHOP2.jar;.

but after this when i run cmd and type make c : To compile the JSHOP2 source files

but it doesn't recognize the command.

Comment: You need to install something like `MinGW` to run `make`.

Comment: I've installed MinGW and now i have a GUI showing me some packages what next?

Comment: Did you check if `make.exe` is installed as I mentioned in my answer? Does `make` work on your command prompt?

Comment: yeah i have checked it and i haven't found make.exe anywhere within the installed folder.

Comment: ofcourse i have read the answer. for copy c:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe c:\MinGW\bin\make.exe it says windows cannot copy file specified.

and very honestly i don't understand this line: 
 Then you should be able to build the project by executing make from your jshop2 root folder. Make is not executable there

Comment: `make` is a Linux tool. The jshop2 github repo says there is supposed to be a `make.bat` file for windows, but it's missing. So we need to install `make` on your Windows by installing `MinGW`. Do you see `mingw-32-make.exe` anywhere in your `MinGW` folder?

Comment: yeah its here C:\MinGW\bin\mingw-get.exe